# Unable to play .mp4 files (videos)

Tags: video, ram, mp4

I am running Ubuntu 12.04, and have installed all restricted packages and 354 MB of available updates. However, I still am not able to play video's.

Is it because of low Memory (RAM)?

My Computer Specifications are:

- 512MB Memory (RAM)
- 1.15GHZ Prcessor

Comment: With what video player are you trying to play with? What errors do you get?

Comment: I am using totem ( default ) I don't get any error.. But can't see anything. The Black screen

Answer (score 5):

To install all the restricted packages you are required to install `ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

It will install the following packages:

- flashplugin-installer
- gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
- gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3
- gstreamer0.10-pitfdll
- gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad
- gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly
- gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse
- gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-multiverse
- icedtea6-plugin
- libavcodec-extra-52
- libmp4v2-0
- ttf-mscorefonts-installer
- unrar

You should be able to play mp4 videos after this. If not, install `vlc` and try opening the videos in it.

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

*References: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/ubuntu-restricted-extras-install-ubuntu-linux/*

Comment: `$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`  
`Reading package lists... Done`  
`Building dependency tree`  
`Reading state information... Done`  
`E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Answer (score 1):

You may be seeing this bug in 12.04 - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gst-plugins-bad0.10/+bug/973014

To test you can move a specific plugin to a .bak, then try totem on the file. If it then plays you're affected. The moving of the plugin is NOT a solution though many have used it as a temp workaround.

To TEST on 64 bit install

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-0.10/libgstvideoparsersbad.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-0.10/libgstvideoparsersbad.so.bak
```

To revert the above move

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-0.10/libgstvideoparsersbad.so.bak /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-0.10/libgstvideoparsersbad.so
```

To TEST on 32 bit install

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gstreamer-0.10/libgstvideoparsersbad.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gstreamer-0.10/libgstvideoparsersbad.so.bak
```

To revert

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gstreamer-0.10/libgstvideoparsersbad.so.bak /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gstreamer-0.10/libgstvideoparsersbad.so
```

Source:[Askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143245/movie-player-wont-play-mp4-gxine-does/143374#143374)

And if you're facing that problem , you'll have to use a different player. Like VLC.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, when you open up the video file in a player in Ubuntu, there must come a pop up message telling you - you are unable to watch the video, and then instruct you to install the right extension (Third party) .Mp4 plug-in so you will be able to watch that video

If you are not getting that, you can also look for a specific extension / plug-in that can do the job. Otherwise try installing VLC Media player, most time VLC can play almost everything....

Answer (score 0):

I guess I have similar experience with the following error message:

"Package dependencies cannot be resolved

This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time."