# Cannot play *.mp4 - files in Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: video, h264

I had several tutorial videos stored on my computer, I could run them all, while Ubuntu 16.04.was installed.
Since I have installed Ubuntu 18.10, it is not possible to play any video. I always get the message: File cannot be played, H264-Decoder is necessary.
In the Ubuntu Wiki can't find a solution.
Can someone help? Please!

Comment: Hope this can help you [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384650/how-to-install-h-264-decoder)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to play .mp4 files (videos)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180299/unable-to-play-mp4-files-videos)

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried installing the restricted extras package? That normally covers most non-free media formats.

The command to use is:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Full instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats

Answer (score 1):

Install VLC it comes with all the codecs you need.

Comment: Nope. VLS is unable to open the MRL 'file:///media/.../myfile.mp4. Check the log for details.

Comment: install vlc via snap `snap install vlc`. The vlc that comes from the apt repo was not playing mpeg4 on my ubuntu (18.04). 
PS: I have not installed the `ubuntu-restricted-extras`, just vlc.

Answer (score 1):

The media player that comes with Ubuntu is unable to read *.mp4 files, so you have to install a media player that can read these special codecs, I suggest VLC.
To install it,
**method 1:**
run the following command from the terminal: `sudo apt install vlc`
**method 2:**
open ubuntu software (press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> button then type 'ubuntu software' in the search bar) then search for VLC and install it.

Comment: VLC works. But I think it's a shme, that the mp4 Codec had been working in earlier editions (e.g. 16.04) of Ubuntu Video.

Comment: Well, may be in 16.04, you already installed the mp4 codec that's why you didn't face the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Support to decode MPEG-4 AAC is provided by gstreamer1.0-libav and to decode H.264 there is ffmpeg:

sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-libav ffmpeg